# Error on apt-get update

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get these errors:

```
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default**

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) doesn't reach EOL until 2030, when it'll move from archives to old-releases.  Return your system back to default.  FYI: Treating Ubuntu as if it's Debian can create problems, so using the QA-tested upgrade features is far safer.   You should also clean up your sources to avoid problems (or at least I hope you're using *pinning*)

Comment: Line about `http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian` should be removed manually.